# Single cycle 44.1kHz sampled 1kHz sine wave in c

Tags: c, signal-processing, stm32, trigonometry, dac

I am attempting to create a single cycle sine wave in c. The frequency needs to be approximately 1kHz and sampled at 44.1kHz. This is because the sine lookup table is being fed into a stm32f4 microcontroller that is sampling at 44.1kHz and then out to 5 independent DACs. I have been having issues figuring out how to get exactly 1 cycle of the wave.

Currently I am getting about 10-11 cycles.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 45; j++){ 
    arr[j] = MAXVOLUME*((sin(2.0*PI*sineFrequency*j/44100.00)+1.0)/2.0);
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier to obtain one cycle by looping a control variable from `0` to `2*PI` and precalculate the required step?

Comment: Based on the math, it looks like you are treating arr[] as unsigned 16 bits but will later use it as signed. Is MAXVOLUME 32k? It would be good to provide a compilable snippet to avoid guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your divisor is wrong -- you want to divide by the number of samples, not by the sampling frequency.  Which bring up the problem -- to have exactly one cycle of 1KHz sampled at 44.1KHz, you need 44.1 samples, which is not a round number.  So you have two choices:

- use more samples to get more cycles -- for example, 441 samples would get you 10 cycles at 1 KHz

  ```
  for(int j = 0; j < 441; j++)
      arr[j] = MAXVOLUME*((sin(2.0*PI*j/44.1)+1.0)/2.0);
  ```
- adjust your desired frequency to match the output frequency -- for example 44 samples for 1 cycle would give you 1.00227KHz when output at 44.1KHz

  ```
  for(int j = 0; j < 44; j++)
      arr[j] = MAXVOLUME*((sin(2.0*PI*j/44.0)+1.0)/2.0);
  ```